# How should I handle exceptions in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, exceptions

I want to keep my game running as much as possible for the user, obviously. They would be dissapointed if the game suddenly quits without leaving any notice behind, and it would be difficult for them to reproduce the error so I can fix it.

So when an exception is thrown, say, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, how should I handle it?

My current flow goes: DesktopLauncher > MyGame > Menu Screen / Game Screen / other screens